# Droplet Breakup model solely for charged droplets in electric field?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, surface-tension

At the moment I am trying to simulate charged droplets and their berakup in an homogeneous electrical field in vacuum. I am using a VoF-Method, but as the droplets get smaller and smaller I would need a finer mesh and smaller timestep. So I was thinking of using an Eulerian-Lagrangian approach by identifying droplets below a certain size and turn them into Lagrangian particles. The question then becomes how will I handle breakups for the Lagrangian particles. From what I gatthered there exist droplet breakup models between fluids like KH-RT, TAB, or PilchErdmann. Is there something similar for just electrostatic breakup?